# Android Studio will not allow me to make chains

Tags: android, android-layout

I am following the "getting started"-tutorial on the android studio website.
(Link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#button)
When the tutorial told me to make a chain between the views, I just could not make it work. When i tried to drag a constraint from the editText view to the button view, the constraint anchor on the button turns red and will not allow me to connect the constraint.

I have already tried to manually edit the XML code by adding app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button" under the editText view, but that does not work. I have also tried to delete everything and start from scratch several times, but that does not work either.

[Current layout (blueprint view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDfIM.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running into a known bug with the ConstraintLayout editor in Android Studio.

See:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37325425

and

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137698

You should be able to create a chain by using the "center horizontal" or "center vertical" commands applied to a collection of views which are currently selected in the editor.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem! I tried to use "center horizontal" and "center vertical", but they did not suit my purposes. I guess I just have to wait until Android Studio gets updated...

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to be of some use. I ran into that same issue myself recently which is why I was able to remember that there's a bug in that area. Also, FWIW, another presentation about the ConstraintLayout is this video by the Google developer who also created the new FlexboxLayout, which I believe will also prove to be quite handy in the future: https://news.realm.io/news/exploring-new-android-layouts/

Comment: It appears that this bug is fixed in Android Studio 3.0. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37150532